# Python is not a recognized command error while running flask?

Tags: python, flask, installation

After activating the virtual environment, and trying to run the application file. It gives the following error

`>python application.py
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I have python installed in the same drive and do not understand why this error is flagged, it could be a path error that I do not understand too?

Comment: app python to path. `set path=%path%;C:\Python36;` use this command. Check if the directory is same for you, in case it is not, use the correct directory where python.exe is located.

Comment: I assume you use Windows, so this article may help: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: I added python to PATH which in my case should be D:\Python;D:\Python\Scripts but even after that the error persists